# How to tell is SAS is running 32 or 64 bit?

Tags: sas

I have SAS 9.4 installed on my windows 7. How do I tell if it is 32 bit or 64 bit? On the net, I can see this question answered for SAS 9.2, not 9.4

Answer (score 1):

You can examine the automatic macro variables such as `SYSADDRBITS` or `SYSHOSTINFOLONG`.

I presume a 32-bit SAS installation on 64-bit host would show `SYSADDRBITS 32`

Log all my automatic variables

```
%put _AUTOMATIC_;
```

Log

```
…
AUTOMATIC SYSADDRBITS 64     <--------------------
…
AUTOMATIC SYSHOSTINFOLONG X64_10PRO WIN 10.0.17134  Workstation  <-----------------
…
AUTOMATIC SYSSCP WIN
AUTOMATIC SYSSCPL X64_10PRO               <-----------------------
…
AUTOMATIC SYSSIZEOFLONG 4
AUTOMATIC SYSSIZEOFPTR 8                  <-----------------------
AUTOMATIC SYSSIZEOFUNICODE 2
…
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `proc setinit; run;`

Under `Operating system` it should show something like the below for 64bit linux:

`Operating System:   LIN X64 .`

Or for 64bit windows workstation:

`Operating System:   WX64_WKS.`

Answer (score 0):

```
%put &sysaddrbits;
```

This is the more succinct version of Richard's answer